# Download link error image from firebase storage

Tags: image, firebase, hyperlink, download

Please help me i don't understand where is the problem

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == Gallery_Pick && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null){
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                    .start(this);

```
    }

    if(requestCode ==CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            loadingBar.setTitle("Profile Image");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait...");
            loadingBar.show();
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

            StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");

            filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this,"Profile image uploaded successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                        userRef.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadUrl)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                            Intent selfIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this,SetupActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(selfIntent);


                                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                                            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this,"Profile image uploaded successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }

                                        else{

                                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                                            String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this,"Error..."+message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                    }
                }
            });



        }

        else {
            loadingBar.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this,"Please try again...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please give us some background as to what your situation is, what you are trying to do, how you are doing it, etc.

Comment: Also please mind the indentation of your code so it is shown correctly (adding 4 lines to the first code line should do it here).